# Why createBottomTabNavigator icons not showing in my device?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, mobile-application, react-navigation-bottom-tab

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBI6G.jpg)

These createBottomTabNavigator icons not showing when i run in my device, but icons are showing when i run using web?

what i need add to show createBottomTabNavigator icons. can anyone suggest me.
here this is App.js code from my project. i used

```
import * as React from 'react';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler'; 
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';


import Index from "./pages/Index";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import LogIn from "./pages/LogIn";
import Register from "./pages/Register";
import CplusBooks from "./pages/CplusBooks";
import PhpBooks from "./pages/PhpBooks";
import DotNetBooks from "./pages/DotNetBooks";
import SearchBooks from "./pages/SearchBooks";

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const stack = createStackNavigator();

export default () => (
  <NavigationContainer>
    <stack.Navigator>

      <stack.Screen 
        name="Index" 
        component={Index} 
        options={{headerShown: false}} 
      />
      <stack.Screen 
        name="Home" 
        component={HomeTab} 
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <stack.Screen 
        name="LogIn" 
        component={LogIn} 
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <stack.Screen 
        name="Register" 
        component={Register} 
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <stack.Screen 
        name="CplusBooks" 
        component={CplusBooks}
        options={{headerShown: false}} 
      />
      <stack.Screen 
        name="PhpBooks" 
        component={PhpBooks}
        options={{headerShown: false}} 
      />
      <stack.Screen 
        name="DotNetBooks" 
        component={DotNetBooks}
        options={{headerShown: false}} 
      />
        
    </stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
);
```

Comment: Please add relevant code and what version your using of react native  navigation

Comment: can you share code please?

Comment: Any chance you could [edit] your question to share a [mcve] showing some code that reproduces the problem?  From [ask]: *Help others reproduce the problem...  if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some...Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.*

Answer (score 0):

It must be a problem with `react-native-vector-icons` Try this steps

Open `android/app/build.gradle` and add the following:

```js
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
```

You can follow the instructions to properly install the module on Android: [react-native-vector-icons#install-android](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#android)

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you're saving the dependency in your project by doing:

npm install react-native-vector-icons --save. Including the --save is necessary, otherwise react-native link won't be able to locate the module.

Comment: i did like this but its be like same